# Geodesic approximation algorithms for minimal geodesic curvature

Tags: computational-geometry, b-spline

### Introduction

I am building an application in which, given a surface and a pair of points on it, an analytic expression of some geodesic arc between them is needed, preferably the one with the shortest length. Furthermore, this parameterized curve, needs to have minimal geodesic curvature.

**Is there a suggested tool that specializes in minimizing the geodesic curvature of the generated approximation?**

I am looking for geodesic curvature less than $10^{-8}$, ideally on any given [NURBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) representation of a smooth surface.

### What I have tried so far:

- The `geodesic` [element](https://grasshopperdocs.com/components/grasshoppercurve/geodesic.html) in Grasshopper. This produces a geodesic curve with around roughly $10^{-1}$ geodesic curvature. (reference surface is a cone)
- The `shortpath` algorithm implemented in Grasshopper. This produces a geodesic curve with geodesic curvature roughly of the order $10^{-3}$ to $10^{-5}$. (reference surface is a cone)

**A remark:**
When I assign a value to the geodesic curvature of a curve (say $10^{-5}$), I am referring to the absolute maximum of a dense sampling of the geodesic curvature *along* said curve.

Comment: Geodesic curvature is a local quantity, for a given curve it changes along the curve. Do we mean finding a curve that would minimize some kind of average of the geodesic curvature?

Comment: @MaximUmansky You are correct, perhaps I should have been more clear. What we are looking for is not to minimize the mean of say a dense sampling of the geodesic curvature along the curve. Rather, we want to minimize the absolut maximum of a dense sampling of the geodesic curvature along the curve

Comment: I don't understand the question, I think. For most surfaces, there is a discrete number of geodesics between two points. Are you saying that you want to *select* between these enumerably many geodesics? In most cases, of course, there is really only one shorted geodesic, and all of the others you could choose from are actually much longer.